# How do I show two view controllers in a single view?

Tags: swift3

I'm trying to show two view controllers in a single view.

My current view controller class is shown below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}}
```

What I want to do:

[image]

Comment: without using segue

Comment: Please show your code attempts

Comment: I do not know what commands should I use

Comment: i want to show two view controller scene together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container Views should help you with your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

> "Container view controllers are a way to combine the content from multiple view controllers into a single user interface."

Comment: [Here's a decent youtube link for a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIdgtfdoTEg)

Comment: Awesome, can you mark the answer as 'correct' to help others who have similar questions?